# Spring Boot Application not Working on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have just started creating Spring Boot application on IntelliJ.
Before this I used to use STS tool in ecllipse.
I have just created a starter project from https://start.spring.io/

Imported it in IntelliJ, Cleaned it or Built it: **No Issues**.

Installed it:
`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test`

When I try to debug the main Spring starter project class I get this error. I have no clue how to fix this, can anyone help me out please.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49152', transport: 'socket'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error decoding percent encoded characters
    at java.base/sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:215)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:1196)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:485)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:479)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:478)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:447)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:316)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:720)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:646)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:604)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:431)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:525)
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at ./open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:49152', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I fix this. I have literally not coded anything. This is just a skeleton.

Any help will be much appretiated.

Comment: I am using a mac , Java OpenJDK 15

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is intrigued by how stupid I am. The folder in which I had stored the project had an image in its name which was not recognized by spring.Changing the path of the project solved the issue